# I can't format the desired output correctly

Tags: r

I have been having a problem with the following:I want to change the date format from  "%d%/m/%y" to  "%y%/m/%d" then create a new column with only the YEAR (Extract the year from the column date).

```
data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase, "%y%/m/%d")
data$year_of_purchase = as.numeric(format(data$date_of_purchase, "%Y"))
```

as an example: 08/01/2019 will change to 2008-01-20 but it should be 2019/01/08.

```
# Load text file into local variable called 'data'
data = read.delim(file = 'purchases.txt', header = FALSE, sep = '\t', dec = '.')

# Add headers and interpret the last column as a date, extract year of purchase
colnames(data) = c('customer_id', 'purchase_amount', 'date_of_purchase')

#Delete columns with Blank Values
data <- with(data, data[!(customer_id == "" | is.na(customer_id)), ])

data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase, "%y/%m/%d")
data$year_of_purchase = as.numeric(format(data$date_of_purchase, "%Y"))
```

There's no error message but the new date is not the desired one.

Comment: Please add sample data which shows the date data.

Comment: If your data starts as a character string like `08/01/2019`, use `as.Date(YOUR_DATE_STRINGS,  "%m/%d/%Y")`. The formatting code there is to tell R the formatting pattern of the text you want interpreted into a date, not the output formatting for the date. R dates always print like YYYY-MM-DD, unless you convert them to text (no longer a manipulable date) in another format.

Comment: Use `anytime` package to get the required format and to extract year use `lubridate`. Your final code will look something like `year(anytime("08/01/2019"))`

Comment: data = read.delim(file = 'purchases.txt', header = FALSE, sep = '\t', dec = '.')

colnames(data) = c('customer_id', 'purchase_amount', 'date_of_purchase')


data <- with(data, data[!(customer_id == "" | is.na(customer_id)), ])

data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase, "%y/%m/%d")
data$year_of_purchase = as.numeric(format(data$date_of_purchase, "%Y"))
data$days_since       = as.numeric(difftime(time1 = "2019/03/25",
                                            time2 = data$date_of_purchase,
                                            units = "days"))

Comment: Example output: Date_of Purchase 2008-01-20 but I want it as 2019-01-08. the days_since = 4081 which it doesn't make sense.

Comment: the original date was 08/01/2019 but after running the code it became 2008/01/20. No idea why?

Comment: look into your input date format, it's not  in `%Y/%m/%d`.

Comment: Try this, `library(dplyr) library(lubridate) data %>% mutate(year_of_purchase = year(anytime(date_of_purchase)))`

Comment: 0000@000.com $22 08/01/2019
0000christie@gmail.com $174 02/11/2017
0000christie@gmail.com $61 03/01/2018
000@hotmail.com $33 16/12/2017
000@hotmail.com $9 28/12/2017
001nzpi@gmail.com $136 24/10/2017
001nzpi@gmail.com $191 10/12/2017
001nzpi@gmail.com $24 25/01/2018
001nzpi@gmail.com $381 20/10/2018
001nzpi@gmail.com $165 20/12/2018
001nzpi@gmail.com $144 22/01/2019
005moloney@gmail.com $35 18/12/2017
007cadbury@gmail.com $81 26/12/2017
007cadbury@gmail.com $43 06/02/2019
007cadbury@gmail.com -$43 21/02/2019
007daws@gmail.com $13 01/08/2018

Comment: That's not how you paste the data. Use `head` command and copy paste the output in case your `dataframe` has many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library("lubridate") ## year comes from this package

Input
data <- fread("customer_id  purchase_amount date_of_purchase
0000@000.com    $22     08/01/2019
0000christie@gmail.com  $174    02/11/2017
0000christie@gmail.com  $61     03/01/2018
000@hotmail.com $33     16/12/2017")

Your code
data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase,"%d/%m/%Y")
data$year_of_purchase <- year(data$date_of_purchase)

OutPut:
              customer_id purchase_amount date_of_purchase year_of_purchase
1:           0000@000.com             $22       2019-01-08             2019
2: 0000christie@gmail.com            $174       2017-11-02             2017
3: 0000christie@gmail.com             $61       2018-01-03             2018
4:        000@hotmail.com             $33       2017-12-16             2017
```

Comment: Yes Jason. This is Exactly what I'm looking for. I'll install the package. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

X$newdate <- strptime(as.character(X$date), "%d/%m/%Y")

format(X$newdate, "%Y-%m-%d")